# why cannot write sum in RANK in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to Power BI and trying some measure using RANKX.

When I write

VAL = SUM('Table'[Value])

rank = RANKX(ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Cat]),[VAL],,DESC) which works;

but
rank = RANKX(ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Cat]),SUM('Table'[Value]),,DESC) doesn't.

Can I know why it happens?
and I also don't know why adding ALLCEPT can rank value within a group.

Can anyone help me on how dax works in rankx? Thank you very much!

| Cat | Sub Cat | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 1 |
| A | b | 2 |
| A | c | 3 |
| A | d | 4 |
| B | e | 5 |
| B | f | 6 |
| B | g | 7 |

Comment: first you can check how ALL and ALLEXCEPT works.